# command line to get hidden attribute for file on a NTFS samba share

Tags: windows, ntfs, sharing

I am using "Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS" and I'm having a problem reading if a file on a NTFS samba share is marked in windows as "hidden".  Please help me find either the package I need to install to get this, or the correct command to read the attributes (including if it's marked Hidden in ntfs (windows))

(Please note, this has nothing to do with if the filename starts with a dot.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `smbclient` to view the share and it shows the DOS attributes.

```
smbclient //server/share
ls
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but is there a way to do it using my existing connection to the samba share? (your solution requires me to navigate all the way back and re-authenticate to my server)  I was hoping for something along the lines of `smbclient -L //server/pathtofile` to get the hidden attribute, but I can't seem to get smbclient to run as a single command.

Comment: @Jared, no, there does not appear to be.  You can pipe the command to `smbclient` like `echo ls /rest/of/path/to/file | smbclient //server/share`.

Comment: what about `getcifsacl` ?  It looks promising, but I've read the man page, and I'm guessing the `CONTROL:08404` might be the key to desciphering if it's hidden or not.  Would you be able to point me to a place that could explain getcifsacl and how to interpret it?  (I have tried googling it myself, but nothing is explaining this `CONTROL` line)

Answer (score 0):

You can use smbclient -c 'allinfo hidden.txt' as below:

root@ip-10-0-0-191:~# smbclient -A /tmp/creds //10.0.0.58/share -c 'allinfo hidden.txt'

```
altname: hidden.txt
create_time:    Fri Jun  8 03:04:22 PM 2018 EDT
access_time:    Fri Jun  8 03:04:22 PM 2018 EDT
write_time:     Fri Jun  8 03:04:22 PM 2018 EDT
change_time:    Fri Jul  6 10:42:49 AM 2018 EDT
attributes: HA (22)
stream: [::$DATA], 0 bytes
```

From the output above, check on the "attributes:" line below:
attributes: HA (22)

The attributes for the hidden.txt file under //10.0.0.58/share is hidden and archive (H- Hidden, A-Archive)

The attribute value is 22. You can check the file attribute constants in this link - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-attribute-constants